# Form requirement alerts, do not show up when I use ghost text

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I am creating a contact form. I want to use ghost text in my input forms, but with the ghost text Javascript added to my code work, my form requirement alerts do not work anymore.

I believe it is because the code is reading the ghost text as the form being filled in, and not empty. I need the alerts to show up when people have filled nothing in.

I think I need to make it so the ghost text has no value, but I don't understand how to achieve this.

Here an example of one of my input fields with a form requirement:

```
<label for='name' >Your Name *: </label
<input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
<span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
```

Here is the ghost text JS:

```
<script>// Reference our element
var txtContent  = document.getElementById("name");
// Set our default text
var defaultText = "Full Name*";

// Set default state of input
txtContent.value = defaultText;
txtContent.style.color = "#CCC";

// Apply onfocus logic
txtContent.onfocus = function() {
// If the current value is our default value
if (this.value == defaultText) {
// clear it and set the text color to black
this.value = "";
this.style.color = "#000";
 }
}

// Apply onblur logic
txtContent.onblur = function() {
// If the current value is empty
if (this.value == "") {
// set it to our default value and lighten the color
this.value = defaultText;
this.style.color = "#CCC";
}
}</script>
```

Here is my form alert JS:

```
var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactus");
frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();
frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your full name.");
```

And here is the form alert PHP:

```
//name validations
if(empty($_POST['name']))
{
  $this->add_error("Please provide your full name.");
  $ret = false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i did a little bit of looking around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505208/how-do-i-get-form-values-to-disappear-when-i-enter-the-field) this is what i think you are looking for :)

Comment: Maybe I phrased my question badly :/ The problem itself is not the ghost text. The problem is that my form requirements are not showing up anymore BECAUSE of the ghost text. The code is reading the ghost text as having a value. So if a person goes on my site, doesn't fill in a form that says "Name*", and then hits "Submit", the alert that says "Please provide your name" does not show up. I need to figure out how to make the ghost text something that does not interfere with the form alerts.@Michael Lapan